# Is there any connection to the ancient Rome city in "Burning Chrome"?

Tags: burning-chrome

It sounds like a pronunciation trick ***Burning Chrome*** and **Burning Rome**. Is it just my wrong guess or are they connected somehow?

Comment: That's a bit of a stretch to wonder if they are connected at all. Do you have any other reason to believe they are?

Comment: I haven't found any straight relations between them. But, you know, I actually have some theories, but they all are very vague. So, I was wondering, maybe it's like [Nero Burning ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nero_Burning_ROM).

P.S. I'm a bit disappointed with all this people, who downvote the question. Why is it bad?

Comment: I am afraid you were taken in by a spurious pattern recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It sounds like a pronunciation trick Burning Chrome and Burning Rome.
>   Is it just my wrong guess or are they connected somehow?

No connection appears visible.

The name "chrome" appears typical of Gibson's leet-speak names of the era. I can't find any hint of a connection to Rome in the story, nor on any of the sites that analyze the story.

Comment: Well, that and the fact "burning" doesn't involve fire at all: "we knew we had to break her, burn her straight down, or she might come after us."  It means to wipe out her (electronic) assets, so she's too broke to hire retribution.

Comment: Oh, and the location of the story is some nebulous location in the Sprawl (but not New York or Jersey which are referred to by name).